# How to get ASCII cyrillic character code in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, cyrillic, ord

`ord()` returns unicode code, and I need ascii.

```
>>> s = "Йог" #cyrillic
>>> for char in s:
...     print(ord(char))
... 
1049 #unicode
1086 #unicode
1075 #unicode
```

and I need ASCII. How to get it? (below)

[image]

Comment: As far as I know this is **not** ASCII as ASCII only contains Roman letters,... and has no specifications for elements larger than 128.

Comment: Yes, above 127 (from 128 to 255) symbols are cyrillic. And everything worked fine when I used python 2.7. On the contrary I tried to convert ascii to unicode than. But now with python 3.5 with unicode everything works fine, and if I need ascii i got hieroglyphs. And I need exactly ascii cyrillic codes (multibyte character set in visual studio)

Comment: That's simply [CP1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). Python should be able to convert Unicode to that codepage.

Comment: Yes, it's Windows-1251.I tried to convert, but couldn't get right code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't; there are no Cyrillic characters in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  The chart you've shown is for one of the many ["extended ASCII"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) character sets; specifically, it appears to be [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (a.k.a. CP1251).  In order to get a character's codepoint in this encoding, you thus need to first encode the string as CP1251 and then take the value of the resulting byte:

```
# Assuming Python 3
s = "Йог".encode('cp1251')
for b in s:
    print(b)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this way, got a lot of errors, and now I can see why. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

```
glagolitsa = "А,Б,В,Г,Д,Е,Ё,Ж,З,И,Й,К,Л,М,Н,О,П,Р,С,Т,У,Ф,Х,Ц,Ч,Ш,Щ,Ъ,Ы,Ь,Э,Ю,Я"
Glagolitsa = glagolitsa.split(',')
Glagolitsa

for i in range(len(Glagolitsa)):
    char = Glagolitsa[i]
    print(ord(char))

glagolitsa = glagolitsa.lower().split(',')

for i in range(len(glagolitsa)):
    char = glagolitsa[i]
    print(ord(char))

for i in range(1040, 1104):
    print(chr(i))
```

Comment: i am also busy making a ascii tools lib for python so maybe i will add russian to it as well as other languages

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then this solution should work for you.

```
a = [chr(i) for i in range(1072, 1104)]
print(a)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).